# How can I find samples for P2TR transactions on mainnet?

Tags: taproot, p2tr

Can I ask for a P2TR transaction id example past block 709632?

I was trying to debug one of my scripts and something is wrong when searching for `witness_v1_keyhash`, and couldn't manually find one in the blockchain explorers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taproot activated in block 709 632, but the first P2TR transactions were in block 709 635. A few P2TR transactions that may be useful for test vectors would be:

- [33e7…9036](https://blockstream.info/tx/33e794d097969002ee05d336686fc03c9e15a597c1b9827669460fac98799036), the first P2TR transaction
- [3777…35c8](https://blockstream.info/tx/37777defed8717c581b4c0509329550e344bdc14ac38f71fc050096887e535c8), the first transaction with both a P2TR scriptpath and a P2TR keypath input
- [83c8…7d82](https://blockstream.info/tx/83c8e0289fecf93b5a284705396f5a652d9886cbd26236b0d647655ad8a37d82) with multiple P2TR keypath inputs
- [905e…d530](https://blockstream.info/tx/905ecdf95a84804b192f4dc221cfed4d77959b81ed66013a7e41a6e61e7ed530), the first scriptpath 2-of-2 multisig spend
- [2eb8…b272](https://blockstream.info/tx/2eb8dbaa346d4be4e82fe444c2f0be00654d8cfd8c4a9a61b11aeaab8c00b272), the first use of the new Tapscript opcode `OP_CHECKSIGADD`

You could find all P2TR transactions via a blockexplorer for example on blockchair.com by filtering the [transaction outputs for `type(witness_v1_taproot)` and `is_spent(true)`](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/outputs?s=value(desc)&q=type(witness_v1_taproot),is_spent(true)#f=transaction_hash,index,time,value,value_usd,recipient,spending_transaction_hash,spending_time,spending_value_usd,cdd,type,is_spent).

Comment: For the final transaction you list, I see where the internal public key should be is: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001. What does that mean in this context? Also I see the Schnorr signatures here are 65 bytes, but I thought Schnorr signatures were typically 64 bytes. In BIP 342, under "Signature Validation" it mentions this, but I'm not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On mainnet there are a number of P2TR transactions in block 709635. A few transaction IDs are included in the index of my bitcoin-dev [mailing list post](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2021-November/019598.html).

Comment: This answer could be improved by including a txid, given that this was the main request of the asker. Please don't post link-only answers.