# Example of Schnorr signature on a block explorer?

Tags: schnorr-signatures, input-script

Can somebody link to a Schnorr signed transaction on Mainnet or Testnet?

Looking to see how the SCRIPTSIG differs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find samples for P2TR transactions on mainnet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110995/how-can-i-find-samples-for-p2tr-transactions-on-mainnet)

Comment: Cool. A nit on terminology. It isn't the scriptSig for SegWit and Taproot. It is the witness. More details here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/107872/what-are-the-scriptpubkey-scriptsig-redeem-script-and-witness-for-the-various

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a SCRIPTSIG with OP_CHECKSIGADD...

Comment: This transaction is listed as the first use of the Tapscript opcode OP_CHECKSIGADD, but I don't see it here. https://blockstream.info/tx/2eb8dbaa346d4be4e82fe444c2f0be00654d8cfd8c4a9a61b11aeaab8c00b272?expand

Comment: I want to understand the diff between an ECDSA multisig and a Schnorr multisig at the script level.

Comment: @liliaceae OP_CHECKSIGADD cannot occur in a scriptSig, as the opcode only exists in Taproot script spends, and those store the script in witness field, not in the scriptSig (which is only used for pre-segwit spends).

Comment: @liliaceae: Please edit your question to update the scope of your topic as communicated in the comments, if you are still looking for an answer. If your question was answered by the linked questions, please vote to close as a duplicate.